# How to use BiometricPrompt with CryptoObject to get KeyStore access for both Decryption and Encryption at the same time?

Tags: android, encryption, android-keystore, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION: When accessing the Android KeyStore with BiometricPrompt authentication, the BiometricPrompt appears every time when I have to perform read or write operation to the KeyStore. I am looking for a solution to authenticate only once, and then manipulate data in the keystore as I wish, in a similar way as it is done on iOS KeyChain.

I have implemented biometric authentication for Android so that I can store app API AuthRefreshToken in the application KeyStore secured by the biometric authentication, by calling setUserAuthenticationRequired(true) on the KeyStore params builder (see below). I have followed examples from Google (https://github.com/android/security-samples/tree/main/BiometricLoginKotlin) and other developers and have made solution working successfully. I am now trying to resolve the problem described above for second working day without success, and now considering using BiometricPrompt without CryptoObject, which would be a big disappointment. I suspect there is a way to authenticate once for a period of time, perhaps by setting `paramsBuilder.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(30)`, but I am unable to achieve the intended result.

To get access to the KeyStore and read the API AuthRefreshToken, I use this code:

```
biometricPrompt = BiometricPromptUtils.createBiometricPrompt(this, ::decryptServerTokenFromStorage)
val promptInfo = BiometricPromptUtils.createPromptInfo(this)
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher))

fun decryptServerTokenFromStorage(authResult: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
    ciphertextWrapper?.let { textWrapper ->
        authResult.cryptoObject?.cipher?.let {
            val authRefreshToken = cryptographyManager.decryptData(textWrapper.ciphertext, it)
            // Use authRefreshToken to get authToken from the API
            // The API returns new authRefreshToken which has to be saved back to the KeyStore
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, and I get decrypted data. However, after each authentication on the app API using AuthRefreshToken, the token changes and I have to immediately save it back to the KeyStore. When this happens, I use below code, which displays the BiometricPrompt again. This causes the UI flow to show the BiometricPrompt twice:

```
biometricPrompt = BiometricPromptUtils.createBiometricPrompt(this, ::encryptServerTokenToStorage)
val promptInfo = BiometricPromptUtils.createPromptInfo(this)
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher))

fun encryptServerTokenToStorage(authResult: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
    authResult.cryptoObject?.cipher?.apply {
            SampleAppUser.refreshAuthToken?.let { refreshAuthToken ->
                Log.d(TAG, "The token from server is $refreshAuthToken")
                val encryptedServerTokenWrapper = cryptographyManager.encryptData(refreshAuthToken, this)
                // Now save encrypted authRefreshToken together with initializationVector in the app prefs for future authentications
            )
        }
    }
}
```

How can I authenticate at once with the BiometricPrompt so that I have full read/write access to the KeyStore for, let say, 1 minute or a longer interval without calling the BiometricPrompt multiple times?

I have tried different approaches and tried recreating the Cipher or reinitializing it for a different purpose, however in all these and similar attempts I am getting `Javax.Crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException` with message 'Key user not authenticated'

The keystore initialization is as follows:

```
    // If Secretkey was previously created for that keyName, then grab and return it.
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
    keyStore.load(null) // Keystore must be loaded before it can be accessed
    keyStore.getKey(keyName, null)?.let { return it as SecretKey }

    // if you reach here, then a new SecretKey must be generated for that keyName
    val paramsBuilder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        keyName,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
    )
    paramsBuilder.apply {
        setBlockModes(ENCRYPTION_BLOCK_MODE) // KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM
        setEncryptionPaddings(ENCRYPTION_PADDING) // KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE
        setKeySize(KEY_SIZE) // 256
        setUserAuthenticationRequired(true) // This is required for BiometricPrompt to work properly
    }

    val keyGenParams = paramsBuilder.build()
    val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParams)
    return keyGenerator.generateKey()
}
```

Comment: do you solve this problem? I spend 3 days but with no results (

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to call [setUserAuthenticationParameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationParameters(int,%20int)) during keystore initialisation with the timeout set to the value you want.

```
public KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder setUserAuthenticationParameters (int timeout, int type)
```

> Sets the duration of time (seconds) and authorization type for which this key is authorized to be used after the user is successfully authenticated. This has effect if the key requires user authentication for its use (see setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)). By default, if user authentication is required, it must take place for every use of the key.